# Manually setting initial events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar where I don't want to set initial events in the "constructor", but from  a called function elsewhere in code. The problem is that the even though the function runs, the renderEvents function is not called until the second time it is run.

```
    function reloadEvents(events) {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', function (start, end, callback) { callback(events); });
}
```

This is the function, and it runs on page load. But I need to interact with the UI and run it once more in order to get fullcalendar to render the events.

Any ideas? refreshEvents doesn't help.

Comment: Why can't you call `renderEvents`? Or do you already do that?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior was due to the calendar not even being present when I tried to add an eventsource with events to it. When I moved around stuff which secured that the calendar was indeed ready for events, everything worked.